# Need Binary Tree Control in VB6

Tags: vb6, binary-tree

I just need to ask, does anyone have link to free resources where I could get the control to draw a binary tree using VB6. Note that I am not saying regarding TreeView control in VB6.

I need a control to draw a binary tree like

1

/\

2   3

/\  /\

4 5   6 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a COM API for [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), which is a graph visualisation tool that can render to a bitmap file.  The COM API can be used to invoke graphviz to render graphs and is accessible from VB (or any COM aware langauge).  You create a file with a description of the graph (in this instance a tree) in a textual format called 'dot' and write it out to a temporary file.  Graphviz then renders the file.  You can render to a bitmap file and display the file in an image viewer control.  I've actually seen this done in practice and it works quite well.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Very nice link you have provided. But i m just waiting for some others.